# How do I style Javascript output for html?

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

I'm creating a sign-up page. I use PHP. The PHP has an error code. The error codes are being read by JS. The JS should provide an error message in HTML. The text I get does not have any style.

I would like to be able to style my JS output by CSS. If that is not possible are there any other ways to manage the error messages?

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
  // Add event listeners to input fields
  var inputFields = document.querySelectorAll('input');
  inputFields.forEach(function(input) {
    input.addEventListener('input', function() {
      hideError();
    });
  });
});

function submitForm() {
  var name = document.getElementById('name').value;
  var email = document.getElementById('email').value;
  var user_password = document.getElementById('user_password').value;
  var confirm_password = document.getElementById('confirm_password').value;

  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  var formData = new FormData();

  formData.append('name', name);
  formData.append('email', email);
  formData.append('user_password', user_password);
  formData.append('confirm_password', confirm_password);

  xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200) {
      var response = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);

      if (response.success) {
        // Redirect to login page or show a success message
        window.location.href = 'Login.html';
      } else {
        // Display error message
        showError(response.error);
      }
    }
  };

  xhr.open('POST', 'create_account.php', true);
  xhr.send(formData);
}

function showError(errorMessage) {
  var errorDiv = document.getElementById('error-message');
  errorDiv.innerHTML = errorMessage;
  var errorStyle = document.getElementById('error-message').style;
}

function hideError() {
  var errorDiv = document.getElementById('error-message');
  errorDiv.innerHTML = '';
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <form action="#" method="post" class="form" id="create_account">
    <h1 class="form__title">Create Account</h1>

    <div class="message">
      <div id="error-message" class="error-message"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="form__input-group">
      <input type="text" class="form__input" autofocus placeholder="Username" name="name" id="name">
    </div>
    <div class="form__input-group">
      <input type="text" class="form__input" autofocus placeholder="E-mail" name="email" id="email">
    </div>
    <div class="form__input-group">
      <input type="password" class="form__input" autofocus placeholder="Password" name="user_password" id="user_password">
    </div>
    <div class="form__input-group">
      <input type="password" class="form__input" autofocus placeholder="Confirm Password" name="confirm_password" id="confirm_password">
    </div>
    <button class="form__button" type="button" onclick="submitForm()">Sign-Up</button>
    <p class="form__text">
      <a class="form__link" href="./Login.html" id="linkLogin"> Already have an account? Sign in! </a>
    </p>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: You can create a style for the class `error-message`

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can do almost the entire submitForm() function without using JavaScript and just using native HTML

I don't really understand you're question. Are you asking how to style an element?

Comment: `I would like to be able to style my JS output by CSS` You can absolutely do that already. Do you have a specific problem implementing it? Also, submitting your form using JS is completely redundant in this use case, as you're sending a POST request and then redirecting the page - ***exactly*** as a standard HTML form element would

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can do it easily using template literals in JS. Try the following solution:

```js
function showError(errorMessage) {
    var errorDiv = document.getElementById('error-message');
    errorDiv.innerHTML = `<p class="YOUR_CSS_CLASSNAME">${errorMessage}</p>`;
}
```

You can simply style it this way:

```css
.YOUR_CSS_CLASSNAME {
    background-color: red;
}
```

Also see the documentation of template literals. They are ver useful in JS.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals

Comment: Be aware that if the error message contains anything that can be interpreted as html, the browser will interpret it as html. If it should be interpreted as text, use `.textContent`

Answer (score 0):

What exactly do you need to do here?
You are using client-side (JS) & server-side (php) & styling (CCS) and HTML.

The easiest method to pass php error codes to javascript is from php itself.
Use a conditional statement to pass the error into a javascript variable or array or whatever you are trying to achieve.

```
.... JS code goes here...

<?php
if (isset($errorCode)) { echo "var err_code = '". $errorCode ."';";} 
?>
```

Styling will follow CSS properties, just make sure the id or class aligns with your styling.